# Why does the law of large number hold for pseudorandom numbers

Tags: randomness, law-of-large-numbers

i`m wondering why the law of large numbers holds for pseudorandom numbers. Is this a empirical observation such as that the law of large numbers holds for coin tosses, or is this somehow programmed into the way the pseudorandom number generator works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the criteria of quality of pseudorandom generators. They are designed for this (among other things).

The law of great number could be expressed this way: any sequences of bits of size $n$ will be observed with empirical probability $2^{-n}$ for a long observational sequence.

Note that the larger $n$, the more it becomes unmanageable to make such observations. Hence this property is only tested for "small" $n$ say < 32. For any generator, there is always an $n$ large enough where this property will be strongly violated, but it requires an $n$ most often beyond usual observational limits.